# Access field from string?

Tags: c++

Given a string:

```
std::string foo = "world->units.all[0]";
```

How can I pass the value that `foo` represents to a function? :

```
bar(foo);        // Passing the string
bar(magic(foo)); // Passing world->units.all[0] (whatever that is)
```

Note: The string `foo` is user input, however I'm not going to worry about users blowing themselves up since it's all local. The structures being accessed are structs, classes, arrays and pointers.

Comment: What you're trying to do is a real PITA in C++.  Can you use a different language that would make your life easier?

Comment: Answer: Don't do that.  Really, don't do that.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm working on a plugin for a program which is written in C++.

Comment: But why do you think you need to do such a thing?

Comment: The plugin I'm making exports a json representation of the internal data structures. Like `export world->units "units.json"`. The internal structure is specified by an XML document which I'm currently using to generate the `encode` functions for each data structure.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do this in C++ natively. It doesn't have a runtime parser or interpreter. To  do this, you're going to have to implement both.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a map to access the needed value.

```
std::string foo = "world->units.all[0]";
std::map<std::string, std::string*> world_map;

void init()
{
  world_map[foo] = &world->units.all[0];
}

std::string magic(const std::string &foo)
{
  return *world_map[foo];
}
```